# I wants to implement single and double tap on listview

Tags: android

1.) single tap white layer is visible & invisible on row.
2.) on double tap animation runs in my app.
On double click animation is running fine in my app. On single tap layer is visible and invisble on next single click but my problem is that when i make a single tap than layer is shown but than after if i double tap on row than my listview is unclickable even i can't make single click after that.

```
int i = 0;

adapter = new MyAdapter(this, datas);
    lv.setAdapter(adapter);

    // load the animation
    animRotate = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplicationContext(),
            R.anim.rotate);
    animFadeOut = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplicationContext(),
            R.anim.fade_out);
    // set animation listener
    animRotate.setAnimationListener(this);
    animFadeOut.setAnimationListener(this);
}

@Override
protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {

    if (!isAnimationRunning) {
        roundLogo = (ImageView) v.getTag(R.id.picture_ImageView_logoround);
        animLogo = (ImageView) v.getTag(R.id.picture_ImageView_logo);
        i++;
        Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                if (i == 1) {
                    i = 0;
                    if (adapter.isVisible()) {
                        // layer invisible
                    } else {
                        // layer visible

                    }
                }
            }
        };

        if (i == 1) {
            handler.postDelayed(runnable, 200);
        } else if (i == 2 && !adapter.isVisible) {
            handler.removeCallbacks(runnable);
            i = 0;
        // ANIMATION CODE HERE IT WORKS FINE

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I am sure, but I think a modified version of below snippet can be adopted.

```
protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) 
    {
    long timeNow=Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMilis();
    long timeLastTapped=Long.valueOf(view.getTag); // Initially set to zero in adapter
    final int minDurationBetweenDoubleTap=500;
    if(timeLastTapped != 0)
    if( timeNow- timeLastTapped < minDurationBetweenDoubleTap) // 
    {
    //Double Tapped===> Do your stuff here
    }
    view.setTag(""+timeNow);    
    };
```